# Обработка сообщения после нажатия кнопки

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

У меня есть бот и при начале работы он отправляет обычную (не инлайн) клавиатуру.

Я использую `node-telegram-bot-api`

Обрабатывается она как-то так:

```
bot.on('message', msg => {

    const chatId = helper.getChatId(msg)

    switch (msg.text) {
    case kb.btn1:
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Введи произвольное слово например и я выполню с ним определенные действия:')
        break
    case kb.btn2:
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Введи другое произвольное слово и я выполню с ним немного другие действия, не те, что при нажатии на первую кнопку')
        break
    }
})
```

Я хочу добиться такого поведения, чтобы при нажатию на первую кнопку - пользователю пришло сообщение: `Введи произвольное слово например и я выполню с ним определенные действия:`
В ответ на него юзер мог отправить определенное слово, чтоб бот его получил, выполнил с ним какие-то действия и вернул пользователю результат.

При отправке боту нового слова - все должно повторяться.

Так это всё должно работать пока пользователь не нажмет другую кнопку.

При нажатии на другую кнопку все работает примерно так же но бот со словом выполняет другие действия, не такие как при нажатии первой кнопки.

Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня тоже возникал подобный вопрос. Помог ответ: Используйте ForseReply при отправке сообщений с запросами адреса и пр., а затем проверяйте входящие сообщения на наличие непустого поля reply_to_message и смотрите в текст этого поля. В зависимости от его содержимого можно будет понять, какой именно шаг сценария выполняется.